# Mockito.donothing() also check inside the method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, jgit

So,I want to call the donothing() method while writing the unit test for my perticular method, what I understand of using `donothing` is that "it tells Mockito to do nothing when a method in a mock object is called".

But in my case when I want to tells mockito to do nothing while calling the void method, it also checks the information that written inside the method too.
Why this is happen, Is `donothing` method also checks inside the method or it just simply skip the testing for it.?

E.g

this is the method in that I want to call `donothing`:

```
 public void deleteTemporaryRemoteBranch(final File gitFile, final String branchName) throws IOException,
            GitAPIException {
        final Git openedRepo = Git.open(gitFile);
        //delete branch 'branchName' locally
        openedRepo.branchDelete().setBranchNames(branchName).setForce(true).call();

        //delete branch 'branchName' on remote 'origin'
        RefSpec refSpec = new RefSpec()
                .setSource(null)
                .setDestination(String.format(BRANCH_HEAD_REF, branchName));
        openedRepo.push().setRefSpecs(refSpec).setRemote(LambdaEnv.ORIGIN).call();
    }
```

This is the test method :

```
private static final String REPO_LOCATION = "/tmp/JGitClientTest12-repo/";
    private static final File REPO_FILE = new File(REPO_LOCATION);

    @Test
    public void clone23_happyCase2() throws Exception {
     Mockito.doNothing().when(jgitAccessor).deleteTemporaryRemoteBranch(Mockito.any(),Mockito.anyString());
     classUnit.deleteTemporaryRemoteBranch(REPO_FILE,Mockito.anyString());
    }
```

When I run this method it show me the error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid refspec refs/heads/

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.RefSpec.checkValid(RefSpec.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.RefSpec.setDestination(RefSpec.java:337)
```

So why this is testing inside the `deleteTemporaryRemoteBranch` method, even I call `donothing()` in it.?

I am new to unit testing.Any suggestion!!

Also any suggestion for this issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid refspec refs/heads/

    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.RefSpec.checkValid(RefSpec.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.RefSpec.setDestination(RefSpec.java:337)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, `doNothing` does nothing, but in the example that you have put you are not using the mocked class, you are calling another class.

You should change

```
   classUnit.deleteTemporaryRemoteBranch(REPO_FILE,Mockito.anyString());
```

for

```
   jgitAccessor.deleteTemporaryRemoteBranch(REPO_FILE,Mockito.anyString());
```

In other way, that test does not make much sense since by default the mocked methods do not do

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing()